# Authorize.net in magento2

Tags: magento, authorize.net, magento2

I have created a sandbox account and given the API key ,transaction details and hash values in the configurations of magento side.

And given the receipt URL and referrer URL in the sandbox.authorize.net And I am getting the error response in the mail and the order also not placed.

**Your script timed out while we were trying to post transaction results to it.
   Transaction ID: 0
Transaction Result: This transaction has been approved.**

Comment: Please refer Authorize.net developer documentation.If you configured everything correctly then it may be issue because of SSL issue.Or try to enable debug mode and check the logs.

Comment: A transaction ID of zero indicates your sandbox is in test mode, it should be in live mode.  Your relay response URL must be a valid public facing url on standard port 80 or 443.

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem but when I was working in localserver. When I tried in live server it works and response also comes and also redirect on success page with authrorize.net.
So if you are working on your localserver(localhost) then this will be the probelm for you.
I hope you clear.
:)